# Java Hibernate Many To One saving to the DB

Tags: java, database, hibernate

In my database, I have a table **Partner**, and a table **Town**. Those are linked in a way that each record in **Partner** has it's accessory `Town_ID`. Town doesn't know anything about the Partner.

I am trying to do my mapping, such that `Partner` objects have **many-to-one** relationship with the `Town` objects, i.e. every `Partner` object has it's own `Town` as a member variable.

In the code, that looks like the following.

***Town.java***

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Town")
public class Town {

    @Id     // Primary Key: automatically generated
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native_generator", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "native_generator")
    @Column(name = "Town_ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Country_ID")
    private Country country;

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
    private String name; // ...
```

***Partner.java***

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Partner")
public class Partner {

    @Id     // Primary Key: automatically generated
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native_generator", strategy = "native")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "native_generator")
    @Column(name = "Partner_ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "Type", nullable = false)
    private char type;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PartnerHome_ID")
    private Town homeTown;
```

**The problem**

The problem occurs anytime I try to save the new Partner with the already existing Town (a Town that is already stored in the database) - it wouldn't let me, but is forcing me to save the Town once again. The example.

```
Town town = new Town("My town", "10000"); // already saved in the DB from before

Partner p = new Partner("New partner", town); // not yet in the DB

s.save(town); // If I comment on this line, the exception occurs
s.save(p);

s.getTransaction().commit();        
s.close();
```

So, if I don't save the town to the DB (a Town that already exists in the DB), i get the following error:

**Object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing: Town**

- When I do save it, there is no error. Why do I need to repeatedly save objects that are already in my DB?
- How could I just save my new Partner object, and let it reference a town that is already in the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it already exists in the database, then don't create a new one. Get the one which already exists from the database:

```
Town alreadyExistingTown = s.get(Town.class, idOfExistingTown); 
// or Town alreadyExistingTown = s.load(Town.class, idOfExistingTown);
Partner p = new Partner("New partner", alreadyExistingTown);
s.save(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your program you have specified
**Town town = new Town("My town", "10000");** .

That clearly shows you are creating a new instance of town. If you really want to use existing town then fetch it from database. If you want to fetch the instance by name "My Town" you can try this code.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction(); 
            Criteria crt = session.createCriteria(Town.class);      
            crt.add(Restrictions.eq("name", "My Town"));                
            List <Town> towns= crt.list();  
            // If you have only one town then with name "My Town"
            Town town = towns.get (0);
            Partner p = new Partner("New partner", town);
            session.save(p);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } 

        finally {
            if(session!=null&&session.isOpen()){
                session.close();
            }
        }
```

On the other hand if you know the id of the Town object then you can try this.

```
            session.beginTransaction();
            Serializable id =  10000;
            Object persistentTownInstance = session.load(Town.class, id);
            Partner p = new Partner("New partner", persistentTownInstance);
...
```